# O que é "Shape Up"? Ele é um método ágil?

Tags: engenharia-de-software, metodologia-ágil, scrum, kanban

Recentemente, estudando sobre engenharia de software, me deparei com esse termo `Shape Up` e que este fora aprensentado como: *"uma alternativa ao método ágil `Scrum`"*.

Sobre metodologia ágeis eu já entendi os principais métodos ágeis como o `XP` (talvez o mais importante para programadores), `Scrum` e `Kanban` (os mais generalistas). Sei que existe o `Modelo Spotify` (não estudei muito esse), mas não sei se ele se encaixa no contexto.

Esse `Shape Up` chamou minha atenção e fico pensando o que ele propõe para ser considerado como uma alternativa direta ao `Scrum` e por que não ao `Kanban` e por que seria interessante considerá-lo ao se trabalhar com times de desenvolvimento.

- O que é `Shape Up`?
- Ele é considerado um método ágil de fato?
- O que `Shape Up` propõe que métodos ágeis como `Scrum` e `Kanban` já não resolvem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vou responder com base em experiência própria, pois atualmente trabalho nesse modelo. E também usando o [livro "Shape Up: Stop Running in Circles
and Ship Work that Matters"](https://basecamp.com/shapeup) como referência.

## Shape Up

O Shape Up é a forma que o Basecamp, a empresa de onde surgiu o framework Ruby on Rails, desenvolve produtos digitais. Eles definem como uma caixa de ferramentas com técnicas para aplicar em seu próprio processo. Pra entender o Shape Up deve-se entender a empresa Basecamp e sua forma de pensar, opinativa e em contracorrente.

Esse processo de fazer produtos é baseado em três fases principais. Definição, aposta, e construção.

### Definição ou shaping

Essa primeira fase não é de execução, e sim de definir o que será construído. Geralmente participam as pessoas com mais experiência e de diferentes áreas: desenvolvedores, designers, negócio. Aqui será definido o que será feito, mas não totalmente o como. Deve ser concreto suficiente, para que o time saiba o que fazer, mas não impositivo, para que não restrinja a equipe de descobrir os detalhes por si mesmos.

### Aposta

É nessa fase que a funcionalidade ou projeto será apresentada aos gestores e outros tomadores de decisão. Junto com o time que fez as definições na fase anterior, eles tomarão decisões dos projetos que serão executados, ou que serão cortados.

### Construção

É aqui que o time de desenvolvedores, designers e outros construirão de fato o projeto ou funcionalidade. O ciclo de seis semanas começa nessa fase, e no fim do ciclo, o projeto é finalizado ou descartado. Extensões desse ciclo não acontecem com frequência e é desencorajado.

## Framework? Ágil? Scrum? Kanban?

O que posso afirmar é que Shape Up é bem diferente de Scrum e Kanban. Aqui não existe um backlog, os ciclos são de 6 semanas, não existe uma reunião de retrô, o refinamento acontece fora da maioria do time, assim como o discovery. Se definir como ágil é estar dentro das premissas do [Manifesto Ágil](https://www.atlassian.com/agile/manifesto), dá pra se dizer que é ágil sim.

O Shape Up também não é um framework, e sim uma série de recomendações de como você pode trabalhar dessa forma, e ajustar do jeito que bem entender. O livro explica bem as ferramentas que o Basecamp usa, e as compilou chamando de Shape Up. Você pode escolher as que fizerem sentido para seu contexto.

Por experiência própria, o que acho diferente desse método de trabalhar, é que as definições de novas funcionalidades vem na medida. Nem tão definido, nem tão vago. Isto é, desenvolvedores fazem parte do processo de criação do produto, e não atuam simplesmente como "fazedores de tarefa" em projetos totalmente definidos. Aqui é responsabilidade do desenvolvedor definir os detalhes da funcionalidade.